# Sorting three integers

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

To start off, Yes I am working on an intro to programming assignment, however I have spent all day and night trying to solve this with some progress but no success.

The exercise is to create a method that sorts 3 ints from least to greatest. We are not encouraged to use arrays, but at this point I cant figure out how I will achieve this without the help of an array.

I started out with simply trying to figure out how to "sort" 3 integers and this is what I came up with:

```
public class SortInteger {
public static void main(String[]args) {
    int a          = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int b          = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int c          = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    int n1, n2, n3 = 0; 


    if      (a < b && a < c) { n1 = a; }
    else if (b < a && b < c) { n1 = b; }
    else    { n1 = c; }

    if      (a > b && a > c) { n3 = a; }
    else if (b > a && b > c) { n3 = b; }
    else    { n3 = c; }

    if      (n1 < a && a < n3) { n2 = a; }
    else if (n1 < b && b < n3) { n2 = b; }
    else    {n2 = c;}

    System.out.println( n1 + " " + n2 + " " + n3);
   }
}
```

I feel that I could easily reduce the amount of if statements and simplify alot of lines in the above code, however I want to wait until i succeed before I start cleaning up the program. Also, That code works but the goal is to write it as a static method. So after getting this far I began my attempts on converting it to a static method and have come this far:

```
public class SortInteger2 {
public static int sort(int a, int b, int c) { 
    int []s = new int [3];

    if      (a < b && a < c) { s[0] = a; }
    else if (b < a && b < c) { s[0] = b; }
    else    {s[0] = c;}

    if      (a > b && a > c) { s[2] = a; }
    else if (b > a && b > c) { s[2] = b; }
    else    {s[2] = c;}

    if      (s[0] < a && a < s[2]) { s[1] = a; }
    else if (s[0] < b && b < s[2]) { s[1] = b; }
    else    {s[1] = c;}

    return s[]; //I dont know how to return an array, this didnt work for me
 }

public static void main(String[]args) {
    int A   = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int B   = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int C   = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

    int []S = new int [3];
     S = sort(A,B,C);
    System.out.println(S[0] + " " + S[1] + " " + S[2]); 
 }
}
```

I Know I can only return a single object, which is why I chose to use an array to store the three integers and then simply return the single object that is the array. However, the compiler still yells at me when I try it. What am I missing here? I feel like its so obvious but something isnt clicking when I examine it over and over. If I could just be steered in the right direction, I would very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I feel that I could easily reduce the amount of if statements and simplify alot of lines in the above code,"

You can keep using a, b, c instead of making new variables, and swap them based on their comparisons, but other than that, there's not much reducing to be made.

"Also, That code works but the goal is to write it as a static method."

Why not just do this?

```
public static void sort(int a, int b, int c) {
    ...

    System.out.println( n1 + " " + n2 + " " + n3);
   }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    sort(2, 5, 9);
}
```

If you're still intent on using arrays, change the return value of `sort` to `int[]`. Then, change the line `return s[]` to `return s`, signifying you're returning the array.

Comment: Thank you! This really cleared it up for me. Now that I've got it working, The only thing left to deal with is having to return. I made the changes you recommended, however the compiler is upset with me since im not returning anything in the sort method. Which I don't really need to, so is there anyway around that? Or should i just throw in a return n1 just to make it happy? We're still learning about static methods, but if the method is anything other than void, does that mean I HAVE to return an object?

Comment: If the method return type is not void, you must return the specified return type. Look at my answer, see how I declared the method? `public static void sort`. Change that in your code, too. If you just want a function to print something and return nothing, make it of type `void`.

Comment: Ah ok! I didnt actually notice you wrote `void` and mistakenly wrote `int sort` again. That's what was throwing me off. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You're very close.

All you need to do is change the return type of the `sort` method from `int` to `int[]` to signify that you are returning an integer array. Then, at your return line `return s[];` change `s[]` to `s`. You don't need the brackets because you are returning the entire array.

I ran this and it worked for me.